# Athena queries changes on the fly according to the partitions introduced in S3

Tags: sql, performance, amazon-s3, query-optimization, amazon-athena

I have partitioned my DATA_BUCKET in S3 with structure of
`S3/DATA_BUCKET/table_1/YYYY/MM/DD/files.parquet`

Now I have three additional columns in the table_1 which are visible in Athena as "partition_0", ""partition_1" and "partition_2" (for Year, Month and Day respectively).

Till now my apps were making time-related-queries based on the "time_stamp" column in the table:
`select * from table_1 where time_stamp like '2023-01-17%'`

Now to leverage the performance because of the partitions, the corresponding new query is:
`select * from table_1 where partition_0 = '2023' and partition_1 = '01' and partition_2 = '17'`

Problem:
Since there are many previous queries made on time_stamp in my apps I do not want to change them but still somehow transform those queries to my "partitions-type-queries" like above.

Is there any way like internally in Athena or something else ?

TIA

Comment: I honestly see this problem more a "software problem" instead of a Athena thing. I can see your issue and I think if all your old queries are kind of "Select c1, c2 from t1 where time_stamp = #VAR" Maybe you can append to all old queries the partitioning stuff splitting #VAR into Year, months and days right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view from the original table with a new "time_stamp" column.
This column calculate *Date* from date-parts:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT mytable.col1, 
    mytable.col2, 
    cast(date_add('day', trans_day - 1, date_add('month', trans_month - 1, date_add('year', trans_year - 1970, from_unixtime(0)))) as Date) as time_stamp
FROM my_db.my_table mytable
```